# Add class to css after ""

Tags: jquery, css

Hello i have a problem i am using uikit to make a dropdown and i have some problems adding a data class after the css for example:

```
<div class="uk-dropdown"data-uk-dropdown></div>
```

What i need to add is the "data-uk-dropdown". I tried with some jquery but it only seems to add it next the uk-dropdown but not after the "".

what i tried to use :

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
      $( ".uk-navbar-nav .meny-item" ).addClass( "",'uk-data-dropdown' );
      } );
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935191/adding-data-attribute-to-dom

Comment: Add class method takes one parameter that is just the class name. Remove double quotes from the method parameter.

Comment: classes are classes and have nothing to do with data, use `.data()` instead of `.addClass()`

Comment: selector you are using doesn't match html shown

Comment: http://getuikit.com/docs/dropdown.html
I am using this framework.

And for the link to be able to show the dropdown nav,

i have to add data-uk-dropdown after the "" as in <div class="uk-dropdown"+insert the 'data-uk-dropdown' here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to add data attribute not the data class. It can be easily done by.
`jQuery(document).ready( function() {
      $( ".uk-dropdown" ).attr( "data-uk-dropdown","{mode:'click'}" );
      } );`

The above code will add `data-uk-dropdown="{mode:'click'}"` attribute to all the dom element having class `.uk-dropdown`.

i.e. your output will be `<div class="uk-dropdown" data-uk-dropdown="{mode:'click'}"></div>`