# add data attribute dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

My html is

```
<div id="ctup-ads-widget-2" class="caption slide-heading "  data-x="380" data-y="80" data-speed="1800" data-start="1200" data-easing="easeOutExpo">Hui</div>
```

I am trying to change the values of dat=x and data-y dynamically

I tried both below which did not work.

```
<script>
$('#ctup-ads-widget-2').click(function() {

    $(this).attr("data-x", "580");
});
</script>
```

and

```
<script>
$('#ctup-ads-widget-2').click(function() {
    $(this).data('x') = "580";
});
</script>
```

and

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var anchors = document.getElementById('ctup-ads-widget-2');
    for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
        anchors[i].setAttribute('data-x', '580');
        anchors[i].setAttribute('data-y', '30');
    }
}
</script>
```

console screenshot

[image]

error screenshot

[image]

Comment: `$(this).data('x') = "580";` is syntactically wrong.... `$(this).attr("data-x", "580");` should work... how are you saying it is not working

Comment: If you are using data-api to access the value then need to use `$(this).data("x", "580");`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935191/adding-data-attribute-to-dom

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/data/ refer this

Comment: Probably, your DOM is not loaded at the moment of your script execution. Use jQuery document ready or window.onload functions.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev how?

Comment: @Melvin Actually, Zee has already described how it should be done.

Answer (score 3):

You **can't** use it like

```
$(this).data('x') = "580";//won't work
```

Try with `data()`

```
 $(this).data("x","580"); //$(this).attr("data-x", "580") should also work
```

**Update**

Enclose it in `$(document).ready..`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#ctup-ads-widget-2').click(function() {
    $(this).data("x","580");
  });
})
```

Comment: <script>

 
  $('#ctup-ads-widget-2').click(function(){
   $(this).data("x","580");
 
});
</script>

Comment: @Melvin Screenshot is fine but you need to tell us which line you are getting that error.

Comment: @Melvin Have you included jQuery?

Comment: <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: included in footer .. i have added the script to header .. is that be a pblm?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79612/discussion-between-zee-and-melvin).

Answer (score 0):

If data-attribute needs to be dynamically added on an element,

```
$("this").attr("data-x", "5");
```

can be used.

From seeing your screenshots, it's clear that jQuery was not loaded properly.
Use `<script>` tag to load jQuery file before end of `</body>` tag.

**Example:**

```
<body>
...
..
<script src="js/jQuery.js"></script>
<script src="js/yourfile.js"></script>
</body>
```