# how to disabled asp-action link after one click

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i would like to disabled asp=action link after one click
i have a foreach loop to display my book in table in my view
my asp-action for add book in the cart is in the loop but i want to disabled just the book who already in the cart not all books

```
 <a asp-action="AcheterLivre" asp-Controller="Achat" asp-route-id="@item.Isbn" id="disabled" onclick="return myFunction(this);"> Ajouter
```

i try something with jquery but its dont work well

i tried this

```
 <script>
function myFunction() {
    $("#disabled").one("click", function () {
        alert("this book is already in the cart");
    });
}
```

i have this function in my class
its verify if the books is in the cart maybe i should use it ?

```
public bool IsPresent(string isbn)
    {
        //rechercher si l'isbn correspond a un livre de la liste
        AchatLivreViewModel livre = ListeElements.Find(element => element.Isbn == isbn);
        if (livre != null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not trying this simple approach:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
            {            
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @item.Isbn
                    </td>                
                    <td>
                        @item.Titre
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label class="btn btn-primary" style="padding:0"><a href="/Home/About" class="ADD2CART" style="display:block">Add to Cart</a></label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label class="btn btn-danger" style="padding:0"><a href="/Home/About" class="RemoveFromCART" style="display:block">Remove From Cart</a></label>
                    </td>

                </tr>                    
        }
</tbody>
```

And in your javascript, if you don't want to use Ajax, you can manage your cart items all on client side using an array of objects, Let's name it CartItems:

```
    var CartItems = [];

    $('.ADD2CART').click(function () {
            if ($(this).closest('tr').hasClass("ExistingInCart")) {
                alert('Already in Cart !!');                
            }
            else {
                // add this item to the Cart through Ajax or 
                // local javascript object: e.g.: 
                CartItems.push({
                    ISBN: $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text().trim(),
                    Title: $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text().trim(),
                });
                $(this).closest('tr').addClass("ExistingInCart");                
            }

            return false; //to prevent <a> from navigating to another address
        });





        $('.RemoveFromCART').click(function () {

            $(this).closest('tr').removeClass("ExistingInCart");

            var isbn = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text().trim();
            CartItems = CartItems.filter(x => x.ISBN !== isbn);

            return false;
        });
```

Once you need to submit or post the page, you have all the already selected books in CartItems array.

---

**To add this javascript code to your view**, choose one of the options:

1. Put this block at the bottom of your view and copy the above script inside the `<script></script>` tag:

   @section scripts{
     `<script>
         .... copy it here ...
     </script>`
   }
2. copy the script code inside a newFile.js and add it to your view

   `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>`

   `<script src="~/Scripts/newFile.js"></script>`
3. You may decide to bundle this newFile.js

Comment: @Melanie, did you run the above? Thanks if provide feedback.

Comment: hi sorry i dont had time to test it yet i tried to understand the code, i have function in my class Panier i will add it in my question maybe i should use that but i dont know how i could use it in my view

Comment: i finaly did it with ajax

Comment: Glad to hear that. But the above code will handle it all on client side, so more scalable from the architecture point of view. In this scenario, each time a user adds a book to his cart, you contact server through Ajax. Any way, happy you resolved it.

Comment: Dear @Melanie, please accept the above client-side code for future readers, if possible. Since at the time, you asked us not to use ajax as you had not been trained. Thanks.

Comment: ok no problem :) by the way i think i understand your code now except for this part ISBN: $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text().trim(),
                    Title: $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text().trim(), can you explain me please

Comment: Thanks. `$(this)` means this <a> tag that is clicked. `closest(tr)` means select the nearest <tr> parent.  `td:eq(0)` means the first child <td> inside the currently selected <tr> which contains the ISBN number. We used trim() to make sure only data inside <td> is fetched, without any whitespace around, since we may need to convert that string to int. So, on the whole, it means: as soon as the <a> is clicked, go to parent <tr> and select its first <td> to fetch ISBN so as to add it to the Cart array.

Comment: If the <tr> tag contains a class `ExistingInCart`, it means the <a> tag inside it has already been clicked. By adding and removing this `ExistingInCart` to class of each <tr>, we get to know whether its <a>  tag is already clicked or not. If an item is removed from Cart, we filter the <tr> tags to find the corresponding ISBN.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<a href="/Home/About" target="_blank" yetClickable="1" onclick="return foo(this);">  Ajouter </a>
```

And your Javascript:

```
    function foo(input) {
        if ($(input).attr('yetClickable') === '1') {
            $(input).attr('yetClickable', '0');
            return true;
        }
        else {
            // this false returning will counteract the effect of click event on the anchor tag
            return false;
        } 
    }
```

Once an Item is removed from the cart, again you need javascript to select that Item by its Id and change the `yetClickable` attribute back to 1 (in order to be clickable).

**Note**: *This idea above (upon your scenario) works until the page is not reloaded. Otherwise, you need to handle ADD/Remove operations on the Cart through Ajax.*

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you 
but its dont seem to work :( what is the yetClickable attributes?

Comment: I ran the code successfully on MVC 5.2. yetClickable is just an attribute as arbitrary html property we added to store the status of each tag inside itself.

Comment: For DOM properties like checked, disabled and readonly, the proper way to do this (as of JQuery 1.6) is to use prop. Please see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995628/adding-attribute-in-jquery   As you can see in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935191/adding-data-attribute-to-dom  you can use .attr() to add data attribute to an html tag.

Comment: i dont know if i do something wrong but its dont disable my link