# Add attribute do images in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am beginner webdeveloper. I have this code:

```
$(window).load(function () {
            $('.textowaTrescTresc img').each(function () {
                $(this).addClass('picla');
                console.log($(this));
            })
        })
```

This code add class to my images. It's work fine.
I need add: data-label-class="label-class" to my images. In result I need:

```
<img src="garden.jpg" class="img-responsive picla" data-label-class="label-class" alt="Garden Design"/>
```

How can I make it?
Please help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding data attribute to DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935191/adding-data-attribute-to-dom)

Comment: please use a newer version of `jquery`. the `load` function is removed in `jquery v3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```js
$(window).on('load',function () {
            $('.textowaTrescTresc img').each(function () {
                $(this).addClass('picla');
                $(this).data('label-class', 'label-value');
                console.log($(this));
            })
        })
```

Comment: `$(window).load..` is deprecated. Use `.on('load'` instead

Comment: thank you, but in this context it doesn't matter... The point is in `.data` method

Comment: Also if he does not have data attribute he needs to create it with `attr`. Your answer  wont work. ether cover all basis and even fix load as  charlietfl  mentioned. Or do not answer at all. Its a clear duplicate anyway.

Comment: Of course it matters using deprecated methods in new answers. OP is new and should be advised properly

Comment: Something is wrong. Here is preview: http://serwer1356363.home.pl/_nauka/ In second photo I have description on image. I try add this description by this jQuery function, but it's not. working

Comment: @trzew all works fine: `<img alt="Description 2" src="1.jpg" style="height:560px; width:840px" class="dupa picla" data-label-class="label-class">`

Comment: @MaksimTikhonov 0 look here: http://serwer1356363.home.pl/_nauka/ - only in first image I have label with description "Description". In next images it's something wring with. add. data-label-class

Comment: @MaksimTikhonov in 2.jpg, 5.jpg data-label is. not added

Comment: Apply `$('.textowaTrescTresc img')` selector and log it out to console to check your images are present in selection.

Comment: I've found only 4 images. So, maybe it has bad definitions in class name